# Aggregate in MongoDB while keeping fields from latest document

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have documents of the types:

```
{"rule_id": "rule_1", "description": "desc_rule_1_version_1", "version": 1},
{"rule_id": "rule_1", "description": "desc_rule_1_version_2", "version": 2},
{"rule_id": "rule_2", "description": "desc_rule_2_version_1", "version": 1}
```

I want to find all the rules with the latest version while keeping the remaining fields from documents from the latest version.

So I want the result as:

```
{"rule_id": "rule_1", "description": "desc_rule_1_version_2", "version": 2},
{"rule_id": "rule_2", "description": "desc_rule_2_version_1", "version": 1}
```

Please help me out with this.

I tried to do the aggregate but was not able to keep the fields from the latest version document.

Comment: Probably grouping using `$first` and `$$ROOT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could it if `"$top"` is available (introduced in MongoDB server version 5.2).  If `"$top"` in unavailable, see below.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$rule_id",
      "latest": {
        "$top": {
          "sortBy": {
            "version": -1
          },
          "output": "$$ROOT"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceWith": "$latest"
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fTk0-SAC9uG).

If `"$top"` is unavailable, here's another way you could do it.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$rule_id",
      "docs": {"$push": "$$ROOT"},
      "latestVersion": {"$max": "$version"}
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "latest": {
        "$first": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$docs",
            "as": "doc",
            "cond": {"$eq": ["$$doc.version", "$latestVersion"]}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {"$replaceWith": "$latest"}
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e-9m_-6WpfV).

Comment: Thanks @rickhg12hs for your quick response. This solution works like charm on [(mongoplayground.net)] but is giving **pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: unknown group operator '$top'** error in pymongo. Can you please tell me what is pymongo alternative of this?

Comment: @AnkitChouhan  What version of `pymongo` are you using?  What is the version of the MongoDB server?

Comment: pymongo version: 3.7.1
db version: v5.0.13

Comment: @AnkitChouhan I updated the answer with a "pre-5.2 version" pipeline.